# Create multiple dataframes based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I would like to create multiple dataframes based on the value of column `StoreCountryName`. An example of the dataframe `dataset` can be seem below.

```
+----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
|     ReceiptCode      |  | ItemCategoryName |  | StoreCountryName |
+----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
|  0000P70322000039467 |  |  Wrapping        |  |   Japan          |
|  0000P70322000031468 |  |  Kitchen         |  |   Germany        |
|  0000P70322000031467 |  |  Food            |  |   Germany        |
|  0000P70322000032267 |  |  Kitchen         |  |   Japan          |
|  0000P70322000031467 |  |  Food            |  |   Denmark        |
|  0000P70322000031867 |  |  Food            |  |   Denmark        |
|  0000P70322000051467 |  |  Interior        |  |   Germany        |
|  0000P70322000087468 |  |  Kitchen         |  |   Switzerland    |
|  0000P70322000031469 |  |  Leisure         |  |   Germany        |
|  0000P70322000031439 |  |  Food            |  |   Switzerland    |
+----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
```

The result I would like for each `StoreCountryName` value is

```
print(dataset_Denmark)

    +----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
    |     ReceiptCode      |  | ItemCategoryName |  | StoreCountryName |
    +----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
    |  0000P70322000031467 |  |  Food            |  |   Denmark        |
    |  0000P70322000031867 |  |  Food            |  |   Denmark        |
    +----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
```

Also, would it be possible to automatically name the dataframe as `dataset+'_Country'`, i.e. `dataset_Denmark`?

Comment: The second half of your request is somewhat unreasonable because you would be better storing the results in a dictionary. The first part of your request is fundamental to pandas and I assume that you tried something before asking, but we can't see it.

Comment: You store them into a dict , check with`{ x : y for x, y df.groupby('StoreCountryName')}`

Comment: Got it - thank you. For the first part of the question, I split them manually. But I was just looking for a smarter way.